# Template function iterating over its arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have two template functions

```
template <class T>
T &func1(int param, const T &component)
{
    return do_something<T>(param, component);
}

template <class T>
T &func2(int param, const T &component)
{
    return do_something_else<T>(param, component);
}
```

I have to call these functions several times with different template arguments, which results in boilerplate code:

```
auto object1 = some_func(
    [this](int param, Type1 component) { return func1<Type1>(entity, component); }, 
    [this](int param, Type2 component) { return func1<Type2>(entity, component); }
);
```

and similarly

```
auto object2 = some_func(
    [this](int param, Type1 component) { return func2<Type1>(entity, component); }, 
    [this](int param, Type2 component) { return func2<Type2>(entity, component); }
);
```

Obviously, as the number of types I have to do this for grows, this leads to many repetitions. Therefore, I am looking for a way to subsitute everything by something like this:

```
auto object1 = some_template_func<Type1, Type2>(&func1);
auto object2 = some_template_func<Type1, Type2>(&func2);
```

I suppose I have to iterate over the template arguments somehow, but I did not find any information on the syntax to use. If it matters, I am using C++17.

Comment: [Fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). 2. You don't need to specify types in `func1<Type1>` calls.

Comment: Type are deducible `func1(entity, component)` would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
struct Func1Wrapper {
  template <typename T>
  T& operator()(int param, const T& component) const
  {
      return func1<T>(param, component);
  }
};
// Func2Wrapper is similar.

template <typename F, typename ... Ts>
auto some_template_func() {
  return some_func(
    [this](int param, Ts component) { return F{}(entity, component); } ...);
}
```

And you would use it as

```
auto object1 = some_template_func<Func1Wrapper, Type1, Type2>();
auto object2 = some_template_func<Func2Wrapper, Type1, Type2>();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. There is a small bracket mismatch in the definition of `some_template_func` however. I cannot edit it, since the edit would have to few characters.

Comment: @mexx Fixed....